# Heroku shows Application Error for my Django app even though it runs perfectly in my local machine

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku

I've deployed my Django app to Heroku. However, I get the Application Error and found something weird in the log of Heroku: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_site'." I have not used any module named "django_site" and not aware of django having a module with this name.

Can anyone tell me what's causing the errors based on my [Heroku logs](https://gist.github.com/nahiyan/9137c80e7d66e040a7a426533df6c487)?

Here is the requirements.txt file:

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.1.4
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
mysqlclient==1.3.14
numpy==1.15.4
psycopg2==2.7.6.1
pytz==2018.7
whitenoise==4.1.2
```

And my `INSTALLED_APPS` variable in my django settings is as follows:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'cirrhus',
    'flavors',
    'sine',
    'training_sessions',
    'snapshots',
    'training_data',
    'logs',
    'core',
    'input_data',
    'flowers',
]
```

Note: My app runs perfectly on my local machine, even in the virtual environment having only the libraries stated in my requirements.txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my logs, I realized that somehow the settings module was identified as possibly "django_sites.settings", maybe because of the python module "django-heroku" trying to read settings from Heroku Config Variables.

To solve this problem, I created a Heroku Config Variable with key: "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" and value: "cirrhus.settings" to override anything else. Although it works perfectly with Django's test server in my local machine, setting the config variable "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" resolves the issue.